# How save a stored image in a specific directory using Tkinter in Python?

Tags: python, opencv

I am quite inexperienced in Python and need some assistance, Thanks!.

```
frame = cv2.resize(frame, imshowSize)
cv2.imshow('origin', frame)
cv2.imshow('colorized', 255*cv2.resize(bgr_out, imshowSize))
imagetosave = bgr_out * 255
```

This is one part of my code, I wish to save the image it is outputting through the imshow command into a specific directory with a specific name.
I can not figure out how to use the command " asksaveasfilename " to save the image at "imagetosave".

Thank you in Advance. English is not my first language